# telegram bot location python

Tags: python, location, bots, telegram

How to get location from user using telegram bot? I tried this:

```
location_keyboard = KeyboardButton(text="send_location",  request_location=True)           
contact_keyboard = KeyboardButton(text ='Share contact', request_contact=True) 
custom_keyboard = [[ location_keyboard], [contact_keyboard ]]
```

Comment: Which framework you are using? What "KeyboardButton" is?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following:

Call `sendMessage` function with the following params:

```
{
 chat_id : 1234,
 text: "your message",
 reply_markup: 
  {keyboard: 
    [
      [{text: "Send Your Mobile", request_contact: true}],
      [{text: "Send Your Location", request_location: true}]
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears user7870818 is using the library `python-telegram-bot`. For documentation see [here](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/index.html).

Here is a minimal working example of how to request location and contact from a user:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from telegram import (
    Update,
    KeyboardButton,
    ReplyKeyboardMarkup
    )
from telegram.ext import (
    Updater,
    CommandHandler,
    MessageHandler,
    CallbackContext,
    )
    
def request_location(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:   
    keyboard = [[
        KeyboardButton(text="Send Your Mobile", request_contact=True),
        KeyboardButton(text="Send Your Location", request_location=True),
        ]
    ]
    reply_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard, one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True)
    update.message.reply_text(f'Hello {update.effective_user.first_name}',
                              reply_markup=reply_markup)
    
def receive_location(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:   
    print(f"Location is: {update.message.location}")    

def main():
    updater = Updater("BOT_TOKEN")
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('location', request_location))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(None, receive_location))    
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```